# rails4-autocomplete in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I've used rails4-autocomplete gem and I have a problem with displaying hints in autocomplete search form. I can't see any hints.

My **index.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag(products_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: "search-query", placeholder: "namesearch", type: "search", data: {autocomplete: products_autocomplete_product_title_path} %>  
<%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<%end%>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $('#search').bind('railsAutocomplete.select', function(event, data){
  $('#search-form').submit()
  });
</script>
```

I've added requirments code in controller, model and application.js

My **application.js** - manifest

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require autocomplete-rails
//= require cocoon
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

And my **products.scss**

```
.ui-autocomplete {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  float: left;
  display: none;
  min-width: 160px;
  _width: 160px;
  padding: 4px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #ccc;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  *border-right-width: 2px;
  *border-bottom-width: 2px;

  .ui-menu-item > a.ui-corner-all {
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 15px;
    clear: both;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #555555;
    white-space: nowrap;



  }
}
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus {
      color: #ffffff;
      text-decoration: none;
      background-color: #0088cc;
      border-radius: 0px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
      -moz-border-radius: 0px;
      background-image: none;
}
```

My **routes.rb**

```
...
resources :products 
get 'products/autocomplete_product_title'

...
```

My **controller**

```
   ...
    autocomplete :product, :title, :full => true

    def index
        @products = Product.all
         if params[:search]
          @products = Product.title_like("%#{params[:search]}%").order('title')
        end
      end
    ...
```

My **model**

```
...
scope :title_like, -> (title) { where("title like ?", title)}
...
```

I do not know what I'm doing wrong

*Thanks for Your Time!*

Comment: Show me your routes.rb

Comment: Try `get 'products/autocomplete_product_title' , :on => :collection` and what you get in controller?

Comment: It doesn't work :( I've added controller code to my ask

Comment: Have you tried to do it according to http://codepen.io/asommer70/post/autocomplete-with-rails4-autocomplete?

Comment: Yes. I tried.  I did have similar projects and autocomplete worked, but not now.

Comment: Anyone found a solution for this? I'm facing the same problem. Even though I receive the hints, I can't see anything in my view.